# Preview PDF report from SSRS on browser

Tags: jquery, html, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mime-types

I have an SSRS report hosted on Server. I can get the PDF version of the report from this URL.

> http://sql-01/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReports%2fQuotes_Invoices%2fClientInvoicePrint&InvoiceParameter=2&rs:Format=PDF

But SSRS sets the content-disposition to attachment rather than inline. So, Instead of previewing it in browser's default PDF Viewer, It gets downloaded.

How can I solve this issue. I tried Object element. But, It's not working.